# Trying to cast date and time in Teradata

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

I'm selecting from a table with a timestamp(6) data type.

I would like to get the date and time, to the minute, like so:

Currently the data look like this: `03/10/2014 21:54:47.690000`

I would like to select so that the result looks like this: `03/10/2014 21:54:47`

I tried this:

```
SELECT CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) || (EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS TIME)   AS theDate, SUM(VwNIMEventFct.DWELL_MINUTES) AS totalDwellMins
FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP) = 4
GROUP BY theDate
```

But received a message "Syntax error, expected something between the word EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP and the AS keyword"

Also tried concat().

Is there a better way, rather than concatenating, to select EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP as datetime but to the minute?

Also to the hour?

There must be a function that lets you select the output like this?

The ones I found researching the web do not appear to function on Teradata.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMM')
```

But the output was like this:

```
04/18/2014 12:20:44.384000
```

I need it to be like this:

```
04/18/2014 12:20:44
```

Comment: how is your question related to MySQL? MySQL has got a [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. If there's no relation to MySQL remove the tag "mysql" please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never been able to get timestamp formatting to work quite like I want it, but this will get you the desired format:

```
SELECT  current_timestamp(6) AS ts,
  ( ts (FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') (CHAR(10)))as DT, 
  cast (ts as time(6)) (char(8)) as tm,
   dt ||' ' ||tm as FormattedDate
```

Or, there's the new and improved version, compliments of dnoeth:

```
SELECT  current_timestamp(6) AS ts,
ts (FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYbhh:mi:ss') (CHAR(19))
```

Comment: Timestamp formatting is easier than you think, you just need to add that  tricky COBOL style `b` for blank :-)  `ts (FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYbhh:mi:ss') (CHAR(19))`

Comment: Thanks both for the helpful info

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(Column AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

is a  better way to do

Comment: No, it's not, because Standard SQL doesn't allow decreasing fractional precision