# Filtering a data set on dates with a weird format

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column populated by dates in the format that follows...

```
purch_dt
8/18/2014
9/27/2014
1/3/2015
10/29/2016
11/5/2016
2/9/2017
3/1/2017
6/29/2017
12/27/2017
2/25/2018
```

I'm wanting to filter the data set to only contain dates within a certain range, but when I try to code WHERE purch_dt BETWEEN '3/1/2017' AND '6/29/2017' I get the error that says "A character string failed conversion to a numeric value." Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need to [cast the string to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519420/trying-to-cast-date-and-time-in-teradata).

Comment: Even better - store them as [Date](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1143-160K/roe1472241377351.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure of this one, but at least wanted to help. I think if you cast the column appropriately it should work, as in:

```
select *
  from my_table
  where cast(purch_dt as TIMESTAMP(0) format 'd/m/yyyy') 
          between date '2017-03-01' AND date '2017-06-29'
```

In any case, I would strongly suggest storing dates as `DATE` and not `VARCHAR`. Storing them as `VARCHAR` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: So I changed the where clause to.....                                                                    
   where cast(purch_dt as TIMESTAMP(0) format 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
          between date '2017-03-01' AND date '2017-06-29'                                    and that worked

Comment: That won't work when you have single digits for days or months, which you showed in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no format or cast in Teradata that will accept single digit months and days.  So you'll have to parse this ugly string and rebuild it as a date.

`STRTOK` will split on the \ delimiter for you, and lpad gets you your leading 0s where you need them.

```
create volatile table vt_NotADate
(not_date varchar(10))
on commit preserve rows;

insert into vt_notadate values ('12/27/2017');
insert into vt_notadate values ('9/1/2017');


select
not_date,
cast(lpad(strtok(not_date,'/',1),2,'0') as char(2)) as m,
cast(lpad(strtok(not_date,'/',2),2,'0') as char(2)) as d,
strtok(not_date,'/',3) as y,
cast (y || '-' || m || '-' || d as date) as a_date
from
vt_notadate
```

Comment: Parsing is much simpler with a regex prepending a zero before a single digit :-) `Cast(RegExp_Replace(str, '\b([0-9])\b', '0\1') AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy')`

Comment: Regex is pretty much never my first choice...  I tried this:`select Cast(RegExp_Replace('8/1/2018', '\b([0-9])\b', '0\1') AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy')`, get an invalid date error.

Comment: What's your TD release? At least since 15.10 this should work, before there were some differences...

Comment: Ah, that would explain it then.  We move slooooooowly here, we're still on 14.10.